# TFDTable property UpdateTableName has no effect

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac, delphi-xe8

I need a TFDTable object linked to a SQL view (no query, I must use this view!) from a firebird database. The object should accept updates, so I set the UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName property to the underlaying base table:

```
  object fdtPRODUCTS_VIEW: TFDTable
    IndexFieldNames = 'PRODUCT_ID'
    Connection = FDConnection1
    UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName = 'PRODUCTS'
    TableName = 'PRODUCTS_VIEW'
    Left = 200
    Top = 48
  end
```

But UpdateTableName property has no effect: every time I try to update the table I get the message:

> [FireDAC][Phys][FB]cannot update read-only view PRODUCTS_VIEW.

According to the documentation wiki page http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDBottomUpdateOptions.UpdateTableName this property is the ideal solution for my problem but I can' get it working.

I've tested this with XE5 and XE8 -> same results.